# corrupted excel file when downloading it using HTTP request clients

Tags: python, excel, http

When I try to download excel file from the link below from any HTTP request client(requests, urllib3, aiohttp), the client downloads a corrupted excel file. (BTW, the link is import permission status from Korean government)

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://impfood.mfds.go.kr/CFCCC01F01/getExcelFile?dclPrductSeCd=3&srchStrtDt=2019-01-01&srchEndDt=2019-12-31&rpsntItmCd=B01020100000000283CA'

resp = requests.get(url=url, stream=True)
assert resp.status_code == 200, "download failed"

with open("temp.xlsx", "wb") as writer:
    for chunk in resp.iter_content(chunk_size=None):
        writer.write(chunk)

df = pd.read_excel("temp.xlsx")

print(df.head())
```

But when I try to download it from browser, wget and curl, the file is OK.

Comment: please provide a [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In Python, that includes your imports

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, the code is MVE now